# Update GoogleMaps InfoWindow by selecting from a dropdown

Tags: javascript, google-maps, kml, infowindow

I have a map in which the infoWindow contains a dropdown list of dates.  when the user selects a date from this list, I need to update the contents of the InfoWindow.  My points are loaded via a KML file.
http://nctcog.org/trans/data/trafficcounts/index2.asp

I'm currently trying to use the onChange event of the dropdown to call the page that generates the KML to reload it, but this isn't working.

Answer (score 1):

[Here](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_FusionTables_GViz_infowindows3.html) is an example that does what I think you are trying to do.  It uses FusionTables rather than kml for the data source, but the dropdown processing in the infowindow should apply.

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, the example isn't doing anything when items selected from the drop down.

Comment: It changes the information displayed in the infowindow based on the value selected in the drop down.

Comment: OK, it wasn't working in IE, big surprise.  Will look at the code and see if I can figure out whether or not it is useful.  All of my map points are generated on a completely seperate page that is called via google.maps.KmlLayer